TypeError: fetch failed when building Next.js project

`C:\Users>npm run build

amazon-associate@0.1.0 build
next build

info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\associate.env.local
info  - Checking validity of types
warn  - Found lockfile missing swc dependencies, patching..
warn  - using beta Middleware (not covered by semver) - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/beta-middleware
(node:20544) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_UPDATE_HASH] DeprecationWarning: Module.updateHash: Use new ChunkGraph API
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.
./assets/DamageContainer.jpg
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
Import trace for requested module:
./components/modal/ReceiveException.js
./pages/simulation/inbound/receive.js
./assets/amLearnbg.jpg
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
Import trace for requested module:
./pages/authentication.js
./assets/download.jpg
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
Import trace for requested module:
./components/reverselogistics_trexcreturns/side_menu_bar.js
./pages/simulation/reverselogistics/trexcreturns.js
./assets/profile_picture.jpg
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
Import trace for requested module:
./pages/simulation/menu.js
./assets/taping.jpg
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
Import trace for requested module:
./components/outbound-training/BoxSkillDrill.js
./pages/simulation/training/box-skill-drill.js
warn  - Lockfile was successfully patched, please run "npm install" to ensure @next/swc dependencies are downloaded

Build failed because of webpack errors

C:\Usersenter image description here>`
Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Iam trying for "NPM RUN BUILD" but make error, how to solve it, any one help for me.
"next": "12.1.6",
"node: v20.10.0",
"npm: v10.2.3"
